# multiple-polygonal for clip area

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do I use the multiple-polygonal of dust's sources in a wide area at google earth engine? (This polygon is separate and unmatched) The program runs but does not output the error occurred:
A region must be a GeoJSON Polygon or LinearRing. Got: 'GeometryCollection'.
I cannot use from box around area, because that area is big

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand of your question you are trying to clip an image using multiple polygons in a same object. If that is the case, then it should not be an issue. You can clip the image with your multiple-polygons as follows

```
image = image.clip(multigeometry);
```

However, I assume that you are getting your error during exporting the clipped image. If this is the case then you probably got the error because u used the multi-geometry in "region" argument in the Export function. This is because the export REQUIRES you to have a polygon or linearRing to get the extents of your raster. So you need to use the box in this case. However, the exported image will have the pixels you clipped out as masked pixels.

If you would like to have a different image for different polygons then you could iterate through the polygons to create a clipped raster for each polygon and then export them.